# Iterating through a list of view names found by a query MSSQL2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, view

```
SELECT t.name AS view_name
FROM sys.views AS t ORDER BY view_name
```

I found the name of all views in my DB using this. I ve 22 views and I got 22 results so this is correct. Now I want to iterate through each of these views and make a query. It can be something like the following.

```
select TOP 1 *   FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxx should be all of my views. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ' + t.name
FROM sys.views AS t ORDER BY view_name
```

It will return a list of `SELECT` statements for each `VIEW`. The string query can be modified to create different queries.